# Can't edit recieved PHP data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to get data from a database. The server-side language is PHP. In the PHP file that I'm referencing in the ajax call, I echo a div with database information in it. However, when I recieve the data in the browser, I can't make changes to the data using jQuery. For example, when I try to target a specific element:

```
$(data).appendTo("#container"); //appending recieved data onto page

$(data).find("#delete-button").click(function() { 
$(this).hide();
}); //trying to hide button within appended data when I click it
```

it doesn't do anything.
Why is it that I can't edit the recieved PHP code?

I was able to recieve the data using the ajax call, but I just can't edit the data I'm recieving using jQuery.

Comment: What is the content of `data`?

Comment: First off I would say this is a AJAX question rather than PHP, as the page you are referencing will simply echo out the text you want and then for you to edit the text it has outputted then it would be done using Javascript.

Its important to remember the output will just be a string and its then what the client side code does with that string that will affect your program / script

That ultimately will be in JS

Comment: @Rory McCrossan `<div id='forums'><p id='username'>".$row['uidUsers']."</p><div id='forum-title'><span>Title: </span>".$row['forum_title']."</div><div id='message'><span>Message: </span>".$row['message']."</div><button id='edit-forum'>Edit</button><button id='delete-forum'>Delete</button><button id='reply'>Reply</button></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the `data` string in `$()` the second time is not targeting what you  actually appended previously... it is a new fragment instance only in memory

After the `append()` you can query the element directly in the dom:

```
$("#delete-button").click(function() { 
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: that worked, but it only let me hide the button of the most recent data I recieved. Do you know how I can hide the buttons from each div I recieve?

Comment: Ahh...that means you are repeating id's but an id is unique in a page by definition. You need to use classes. Also changes the approach since you would be better of using [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm looking into event delegation now, but I have a question. Would it allow you to reference code you recieved from ajax outside of the success function? Just for clarity.

Comment: Yes... can run on page load and will work for existing or future elements when properly implemented